# Upgrading from 6.10.5 to 7.8.1

Tags: angular, jhipster, upgrade

I have upgraded a 6.10.5 project to 7.8.1.  I followed the instructions to run the generator to upgrade with entities.  That went OK except the previous developer had modified several Spring Boot files so I had to manually merge his changes back into the new files.  Once I finished that merge the application built successfully and ran.  It came up with the basic menu which provides the ability to edit the entities and I tested a few of them with success.  However, it was missing all the customized menu options to bring up the forms the previous developer had added.  I wasn't surprised, so I started a merge process like I did for the backend.  I was surprised to discover that I had to first install the typescript compiler, angular, ng-hipster and a bunch of other stuff I found the previous developer had used.

```
Why is the latest version of ng-hipster dependent on angular
^10.0.0?  That's a couple of years behind the current version
14.0.4.
```

I'm sure these questions will make it clear just how inexperienced I am with this toolset, but I sure would appreciate someone straightening me out if I am misunderstanding things.  I have advised my client to keep the Jhipster system they have because it has great features, but I might have to advise we migrate away if the open source community has moved away from it and is not supporting the angular version of it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to both of your questions can be found in issue [#12909](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/12909) on the official github repository. JHipster moved away from `ng-jhipster` in version [7.0.0-beta.0](https://www.jhipster.tech/2020/12/21/jhipster-release-7.0.0-beta.0.html#most-important-new-features-and-upgrades).

> Refactoring
>
> - ng-jhipster is merged with generator-jhipster - #12909

Comment: Thank you vicpermir.  I'm showing my ignorance again, but I am confused how after upgrading to 7.8.1 and then merging in the code the previous developer added, npm start works fine, but when I run tsc I get a bunch of errors?  Some of the tsc errors are caused by dependencies on ng-jhipster including JhiAlertService, JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks and JhiFileLoadError.  It seems like it's not going to be easy to plug in replacements, or is it?